# Remove Select option from Drop Down with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a problem removing an option from my drop down list. It does nothing when I load the page any ideas? I am using `.remove()` but this is doing nothing.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<title>Test</title>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#bytype option[value='foo']").remove();  
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<select name="bytype" id="bytype">
<option value="foo">foo</option>
<option value="Boo">Boo</option>
<option value="Coo">Coo</option>                               
</select> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You misspelled the `#bytype` in your jQuery selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this instead. Replace `'Your value'` with the value of `foo`.

```
$("#Select ID").removeOption("Your Value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Spelling mistake its not `bytpe` it is `bytype`

```
$("#bytype > option[value='foo']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#bytpe option[value='foo']").remove();
```

You spelled your ID wrong. You're missing the second y.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your selector **bytpe** should be **bytype**